# dynamically resize columns in fastreport

Tags: fastreport

I simply want to resize the columns in my grid based on its content. The code below works 100% for each individual row but it will not change the width of the rows above it. Is there anyways to change the rows above the rows that did change?

```
int wCol1 = 25;
public String resizeCol1(){  
  String sCol1 = ((String)Report.GetColumnValue("resultSet.column1"));
  int test = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(sCol1.Length * 9.2));
  if (test > wCol1) wCol1= test; 

  Text3.Width = wCol1;               
  return sCol1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use "Auto size" option? It resizes the cells depending on the content size..

Comment: there is no auto size option that will move the other columns more to the left if it is smaller and more right if its larger.

Comment: It resizes the cell height and creates the extra space for your content below it, but I guess it's not what you need..

Comment: unfortunatly not, but thanks you anyways

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the `TfrxReport.EngineOptions.DoublePass` property to `True`.
2. Calculate the width in the report script and store it in variable on the first pass.
3. Use `Engine.FinalPass` flag in the script to detect whether it's the final (second) pass and apply the widths.